# Overwriting items retrieved from storage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm making a Mad Libs program. The intent is to reload the text inputs into local storage so that the story is rebuilt upon reloading the page.

I'm not able to overwrite the story with new inputs, even though new inputs are being stored in local storage as intended.

What do I need to do to my createStory function to make it overwrite the text generated from the retrieve function?  For some reason, 'document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = var isn't working.

Javascript:

```
var myStory = "A {{adjective}} {{noun}} ventured out into the world in search of {{thing}}. "

var adjective = 'adjective';
var noun = 'noun';
var thing = 'thing';


function retrieve() {
    var adjective = localStorage.getItem('adjective');
    var noun = localStorage.getItem('noun');
    var thing = localStorage.getItem('thing');
    myStory = myStory.replace(/(.*)({{adjective}})(.*)({{noun}})(.*)({{thing}})(.*)/g, '$1' + adjective + '$3' + noun + '$5' + thing + '$7');
    document.getElementById('storyResult').innerHTML=myStory;
}

function createStory () {
    var adjective = document.getElementById('adjective').value;
    var noun = document.getElementById('noun').value;
    var thing = document.getElementById('thing').value;
    localStorage.adjective = document.getElementById('adjective').value;
    localStorage.noun = document.getElementById('noun').value;
    localStorage.thing = document.getElementById('thing').value;
    myStory = myStory.replace(/(.*)({{adjective}})(.*)({{noun}})(.*)({{thing}})(.*)/g, '$1' + adjective + '$3' + noun + '$5' + thing + '$7');
    document.getElementById('storyResult').innerHTML="";
    document.getElementById('storyResult').innerHTML=myStory;
    console.log(myStory);
};
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>
<body onload="retrieve()">
    <h1>Create a Story</h1>
    <p> Adjective </p><input type="text" id="adjective">
    <p> Noun</p><input type="text" id="noun">
    <p> Thing </p><input type="text" id="thing">
    <br><button onclick="createStory()"> Tell your tale.</button><button onclick="clear()">Clear</button>

    <div id='storyResult'> </div>


</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: I guess you are defining 'var' outside the functions and re-defining it inside each function again. This may create non-shared variables. Try not to create variables inside your function with the same name as the outside ones.

Comment: Must've been it, because I just changed a few names and that did the trick.

Thank you.